# Integer representation as float, clarification needed

Tags: c, floating-point, number-formatting

Take

```
int x = 5;
float y = x;

//"I know it's a float .. you know it's a float .. but take it's address
// and pretend you're looking at an integer and then dereference it"

printf("%d\n", *(int*)&y); //1084227584
```

**Why am i seeing this number?**

- 5 in binary is `0101`
- 5 can be thought of as `(1.25 * 2^2)`, which means that

Can be represented as:

```
[sign bit]                              - 0
[8 bits worth of exp] - 129 (129-127=2) - 1000|0001
[23 bits of .xxxxxxx] - 25              - 1100|1
```

Put together, i have

```
[sign bit][8 bits worth of exp][23 bits worth of .xxx]
0         10000001             11001000000000 //2126336
```

What am i missing please?

Comment: Floating point representation can vary based on your architecture and environment.  What is your run-time environment for this code?

Comment: hmm .. running on a 64 bit mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have pointed out it's not portable... but you know this already, and you've specified 64-bit OS X. Basically, you have the mantissa wrong. `1.25` is represented with an implicit leading bit for `1.0`. The first explicit bit of the mantissa represents `0.5` and the second bit `0.25`. So the mantissa is actually: `01000000000000000000000`.

The sign bit `0`, and biased exponent `10000001`, followed by the mantissa gives:
`0x40a00000` which is `1084227584` decimal.

Comment: @JAM ? I've already provided sign, exponent and mantissa bit patterns.

Answer (score 0):

**Why am i seeing this number?** Because you are printing a float as an int.

I know, I know, you clearly already know this, but the bottom line is the behaviour is undefined. On your system are ints and floats the same size? Have you looked up the standards your compiler uses to store floating points?

Comment: Well, the idea is to see how casting to int* changes the way bits are understood by a compiler. I certainly expect a different (big) number, just want to understand why I am seeing what I am seeing